# How to position text left of center image (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have an image centered in the middle of the div, and some text that I want to appear left of it. However, the text appears leftward and **below** it. I want the text to flow around the image from the left, like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|blah blah ------------------------------------     |
|blah      |     Centered image              |      |
|          |                                 |      |
|          -----------------------------------      |
|                                                   |                  
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Here's an image of what it looks like currently:

[image: preview]

```css
.playermedia1 {
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background-color:white;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
}

.image {
  width:475px;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playermedia1">
  <a href="https://i.imgur.com/WKBkmTN.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="image"><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRok.jpg' class="image"></a>
  <p>text here</p>
</div>
```

One thing I tried is switching the text to be above the image, so the "p" tag is written before the "a" tag. This is what that looks like:

[image: desired]

To be clear, I want the text and image to be at the same level. Any suggestions?

Comment: does `display: inline-block;` work for you?

Comment: `<p>` is a block-level Element *(so is a <div>)*, so it breaks a line.  You may want to look into using `flex-box`, or a `grid` layout so you have even distribution of your Elements... or use `position:absolute;` on a `position:relative;` parent... or use a `float:left;`... or `display:inline-block;` so the line doesn't break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make `.playermedia1` a flex box and give it a `::after` pseudo element, then assign `flex: 1` to the paragraph and the pseudo element.

```css
.playermedia1 {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  display: flex;
}

.playermedia1::after {
  content: '';
}

.playermedia1::after, .playermedia1 p {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 475px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playermedia1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <a href="https://i.imgur.com/WKBkmTN.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="image"><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRok.jpg' class="image"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a good use-case for CSS grid.

The containing element can have `display: grid` and a grid template with three columns.

The first column is `1fr` to fill up 1 portion of the available space.

The second column is `475px` wide (or however much room you want your image to take up).

The third column is `1fr` again to fill up a second portion of the available space.

Because the first and third columns split the remaining space evenly, they will automatically center the second column.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "caption image ..."
  /  1fr     475px 1fr;
}

.image {
  grid-area: image;
}

.caption {
  grid-area: caption;
}
```

```html
<figure class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/475x300" class="image" alt="a 475x300 pixel placeholder image" />
  <figcaption class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox solution to this would be as follows:

```css
.playermedia1{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /** fill up its parent container, this is optional **/
  display: flex; /** this is important, tells the container to operate as a flex container **/
}
```

```html
<div class="playermedia1">
  <div class="text__div">
    <p>text here blahhhhhhhhhhh</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img__div">
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/WKBkmTN.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="image"><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRok.jpg' class="image"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm trying to do this I always have a better experience when I give containers a background color so I can see how they are filling the space within each other. The example you have here could probably have a few different implementations (CSS Grid could be good) but the one that comes to mind for me is to use Flex with columns and center your image in the middle column.

I kept the background colors for reference but they can be removed by deleting the classnames and the styles.

```css
.playermedia1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1;
}

.image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="orange flex">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="playermedia1 aqua flex">
    <div class="red image">
      <a href="#">
        <img src='../img/1.jpeg'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align items on the same level you can use the **display: flex** something like:

```
<div class="playermedia1">
   <p>text here</p>
   <a href="https://i.imgur.com/WKBkmTN.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> 
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/WKBkmTN.jpg' class="image">
   </a>    
</div>



.playermedia1 {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 10%;
 } 
 .image {
    width:475px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the image size change and still be centered within it's parent node *(half of the screen width in this case)* then I would use a `<div>` with a `background-image`. Here's my two cents:

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{ /* set font-size individually or white space may be an issue */
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; outline:none; overflow:hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; user-select:none;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; flex-wrap:wrap; gap:7px; padding:5px; overflow-y:auto;
}
.main>*{
  flex:1; width:50%;
}
p{
  font-size:18px; text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.center_img{
  background-position:center top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#mc_img{
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRok.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <p id='blah'>blah blah blah TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEST more here</p>
    <div class='center_img' id='mc_img'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code simple do using Flex Box:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Your Text Here</p> 
  <img src="img.png" />
<div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```